# Alternative to name attribute on image input in HTML5

Tags: html, input

HTML5 does not $_POST the 'name' attribute for image inputs.

I am trying to find an alternative so that my server-side validation checks can identify which submit button in the form has been clicked on. Can anyone offer suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does post the name attribute but it posts as two variables, appending `_x` and `_y` to the name.  So [this example](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/forms2/test-image-buttons.html):

```
<form action="collect.php" method="post">
  <label>Image button 1: <input type="image" src="Calvin5.gif" alt="calvin5" name="calvin5"></label><br>
  <label>Image button 2: <input type="image" src="Calvin6.gif" alt="calvin6" name="calvin6"></label><br>
</form>
```

Will, when you click on the first button, result in values something like:

```
calvin5_x : 33
calvin5_y : 54
```

In your `$POST` array.